# What is the difference between window.rootviewControoler VS [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, window, rootviewcontroller

What is the difference between these two kinds of View ***Controller?window.rootviewControoler VS [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController***? I can't see window.rootviewcontroller in the stack trace.